# Parametros opcionales del tipo ?id=1 en blade/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Soy nuevo en laravel, y hasta ahora, en todos los ejemplos que vi, pasan los parametros opcionales de la siguiente forma

> Route::get('tienda/productos/{id?}','TiendaController@producto')->name('mostrarProducto');

Luego en el controlador:

> public function producto($id) { return "Esto muestra un producto.
>   Recibiendo $id"; }

Y en la vista:

> a href="{{ route('mostrarProducto', ['id' => $producto->id])
>   }}">{{producto->nombre}}

Pero nunca vi un ejemplo que muestre como pasar parametros de la siguiente forma:

> ...tienda/productos?id=1

Ni como recuperarlos en el controlador. Es una mala practica hacerlo de esta forma? Para el ejemplo que puse me parece mas practico pasarlo de la primer forma. Pero que pasa si quisiera ordenar la pagina por precio descendente por ej? Ahi creo que seria mas practico pasar el parametro asi:

> tienda/productos?ordenar_por=titulo&direccion=DESC

Comment: Pero quisiera que el usuario me dijera desde la vista si quiere ordenar por nombre, por precio, etc. Como convendria pasar esos parametros? Yo lo resolvi mandandolo mediante un formulario, pero no se si es lo mas recomendable.

Comment: Gracias, mi duda mas que nada era para saber si era una mala practica hacerlo de la segunda manera. Y veo que lo es jaja

Comment: Lo que planteas es casi como retroceder los avances que ha hecho Laravel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Haría una distinción entre los parámetros para [`CRUD`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) que ya trae Laravel y los que vas a utilizar para *filtrar* vistas.

Teniendo en cuenta que Laravel [automáticamente](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) resuelve el modelo a partir del ID que pasas, podría considerarse una mala práctica pasar los parámetros de otra forma. En principio porque no hace falta y porque probablemente termines implementando funcionalidades que Laravel ya trae.

Podes no utilizar IDs y usar *slugs* en su lugar, como bien dice Shaz. Yo uso el paquete [cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable). Otra opción es utilizar [FakeId](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId/).

Ahora, en cuanto a los parámetros que se utilizan para *modificar* una vista, no veo ningún problema en enviarlos por `GET`. Si no los envías de esa manera, cada vez que quieras agregar un *filtro* nuevo te vas a ver obligado a actualizar las rutas.

Ejemplo combinando ambas cosas:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

```
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = Product::orderBy($request->input('ordenar_por', 'titulo'), $request->input('direccion', 'desc'))->get();

        return view('products.index', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function show(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        // Si quisieras realizar alguna operación con los
        // parámetros enviados por GET, tenés acceso a $request.

        return view('products.show', ['product' => $product]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente ese era mi problema, porque tambien queria filtrarlo por categoria, entonces tenia que poner como ruta: url/productos/categoria/{id?}/{ordenar_por?}/{direccion?}. El problema es que si no le pasaba algun parametro me terminaba resolviendo la ruta asi: url/categoria/5// y me daba error. Finalmente lo resolvi agregandole valor por defecto a los parametros en el controlador, pero me parecio medio engorroso. Con respecto a pasarlo por get a traves de un form, lo hice con un select con value 'precio desc' por ej, y luego obtengo cada palabra para pasarlo al orderBy.

Comment: Por qué el voto negativo? Quisiera saber si estoy recomendado algo que es incorrecto.

Comment: No se de quien es ese voto, yo te di un voto positivo.

Answer (score 2):

No es una mala práctica como tal, simplemente es menos legible y/o menos «bonito».

Una URL que muestre `misitio.com/tienda/productos?id=1` es menos interesante para los motores de búsqueda (y para algunos usuarios) que una que muestre `misitio.com/tienda/productos/curso-de-seo` (tomando el routeKey como un slug que generas) y es incluso más legible y limpio que la URL sea `misitio.com/tienda/productos/1`.

En conclusión, puedes crear slugs (hay paquetes para eso en caso que no quieras hacerlo manualmente) y puedes aprovechar incluso la sesión o un formulario oculto para pasar algunos parámetros y no reflejarlos en la URL.

Answer (score 0):

mas bien una practica innecesaria, laravel te da herramientas para que tu ruta se vea 
url/producto/1

no veo ningun escenario donde necesites pasar la variable de la segunda manera.. en caso de ordenar tu ruta seria:

```
route::get('pruductos/{parametro}/{orden}', controller@metodo);
```

y en la url se veria: url/productos/titulo/DESC

y en el controlador los recibirias

```
public function productos($parametro, $orden) {
```

de cualquier forma para este tipo de busquedas es recomendable usar post y no get.. pero igual se puede

Comment: Si, eso es lo que estaba haciendo, pero me parecio raro, no se. En fin, no vi ejemplos de lo de url?id=... porque seria una mala practica. Gracias